# Connect with Pymssql / Adaptive Server connection failed (Windows.net vs Azure.com)

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pymssql

I am trying to connect to a new database using the below method I have used many times previously:

```
import pymssql
server = "servername.database.windows.net"
user = "user"
password = "pwd"
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "DB")
```

I am getting this error message:

```
MSSQLDatabaseException: (20004, b'DB-Lib error message 20004, severity 9:\nRead from the server failed (servername.database.windows.net:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Connection reset by peer (54)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (servername.database.windows.net:1433)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (servername.database.windows.net:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Operation timed out (60)\n')
```

One of the first suggestions from other posts is to check the install of FreeTDS. My FreeTDS is up to date and I have had no problem connecting to another server: "server2.cloudapp.azure.com". Both are azure sqlserver's so I am unsure what the connection issue could be. Why would this be? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other questions? If my answer helps, could you please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot, and found a solution.

Seems that the `pymssql` module you installed directly with pip from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/) cannot work normallywith PaaS Azure SQL. You need to follow the official tutorial ([Configure development environment for pymssql Python development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15)) to download specific whl file and install it manually.

In my case, I use Windows OS with Python 3.7, so I download `pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`. `cp37` for python version 3.7. `win` for Windows OS. `amd64` for 64 bit version.  You need to choose right one based on your environment.

Then install the downloaded module with `pip install {your_whl_file}`. After that, I can connect to my Azure SQL:

```
import pymssql

server = 'jackdemo.database.windows.net'
database = 'jackdemo'
username = 'jack@jackdemo'
password = '***********'

cnxn = pymssql.connect(server, username, password, database)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Users")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Result:

[image]

---

By the way, I may try to explain why you can connect to sql server with *.cloudapp.azure.com. Based on the URI path, it seems to be a DNS name for Azure VM. If so, the pymssql module would woek fine with the sql server on that VM, because it is not the PaaS Azure SQL.

Another suggestion is to use `pyodbc`. I see the samples from Azure SQL documentation use it. It may cause less trouble.